# How to make my custom live Debian-based? Experiencing some problems

Tags: linux, image, customization, debian-based

### The need

Recently I've started flirting with the idea of making my own customized Debian live distro. My aim is to have an USB stick with Debian, specific packages, custom scripts and files installed inside. In this way, I can take my OS with everything I need to work with  without taking my laptop with me. Furthermore, It will be specially useful in case I just wanted to replicate the OS without the hassle of installing every single packages and further customizations over again.

### The research

So I decided to go for it and educate myself on the subject. I've found the Linux from scratch project (LFS), but to be honest, it will take me lots of time I currently cannot afford to invest (But seriously thinking for the future).

I decided to use the live-build project scripts based on the instructions and examples of their manual. http://live.debian.net/manual/3.x/html/live-manual.en.html

### The problem

So far, I've built a `hybrid.iso` image with a custom selection of packages by specifying them in the `/config/packages-list/mylist.list.chroot`.

Then I tried to copy my custom scripts, files and software inside specific folders under the chroot directory just created,

i.e.

```
mkdir chroot/etc/skel/<custom dir here>
```

or

```
cp <some file or script> chroot/usr/local/bin/
```

and then run

```
lb build binary
```

The problem is that the iso doesn't get built after the first time I run `lb build` and the customizations done on the chroot directory are deleted every time I try to build it again.

I've tried...

```
lb clean --binary
lb clean --stage
lb build binary
```

or

```
lb build binary iso
```

So what am I missing? How can I add custom files, folders, scripts to my custom live Debian without downloading every single package over again?

why isn't the iso image built again after the first time I run `lb build`?

Thanks in advance...

P.D: I decided to be very detailed on the writing so anyone could understand, specially those that want to try the same...

Comment: See my solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29906894/installing-remastersys-on-debian?s=2|0.0000

Fredson Phiri

Answer (score 0):

I am conscious about LFS too. But, this

> My aim is to have an USB stick with Debian, specific packages, custom
>   scripts and files installed inside.

and this

> it will take me lots of time I currently cannot afford to invest

made me pointing to my answer

I have two suggestions. The easy one, use tools like **remastersys** or **live-magic**.

[Follow this link.](http://www.maketecheasier.com/6-tools-to-easily-create-your-own-custom-linux-distro/)

The difficult one, follow the **official documentation**  to how to creat a custom debian cd.

[Debian official doc](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianCustomCD)

Answer (score 0):

This answer comes a year late for the original poster, but for future searchers: don't add files directly to the chroot. Instead, make a folder structure in `config/includes.chroot`. Then your customizations will be retained when you rebuild the image.

See the section "Live/chroot local includes" in the debian-live manual: http://live.debian.net/manual/4.x/html/live-manual.en.html#506