# Installing Remastersys on Debian

Tags: operating-system, installation, debian

I've been trying to install Remastersys on my OS and haven't been able to.
I've tried using the terminal using the following commands:

```
wget -O- http://www.remastersys.com/debian/remastersys.gpg.key | apt-key add -
```

This one gives this error:

```
 gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found
```

I also tried with:

```
sudo apt-get install remastersys
```

which says that that package hasn't been located

Finally, I downloaded a deb package from internet, but I haven't been able to open it.

Is there any other possible way I can use this program?

Comment: I've been looking for the errors but haven't solved any yet.

Comment: Try asking at [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Answer (score 0):

Hie
It seems remastersys is not well supported in latest distribution. I suggest you use [systemback](https://launchpad.net/systemback). It also has some extra nice features. I have been able to successfully create an iso with it and written it to a 4G memory stick. However it failed to write to a 16G memory stick. I had to use unetbootin for that. My suggestion is to use [systemback](https://launchpad.net/systemback) for creating iso and then unetbootin for writing to usb.

Hope this helps
Fredson

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it supports debian:
This PPA contain the stable version of Systemback.

Currently supported Ubuntu releases:
- 14.04.X LTS
- 15.04
- 15.10